# How do I update .NET framework 4 without internet connection?

Tags: .net-framework, .net-4.0

I've tried the standalone installer but it seems that it only installs the original version (clr.dll version is 4.0.30319.1)

note: I'm trying to install the full version and not the client profile

Answer (score 1):

The CLR.dll version number does not correspond to the .NET framework version number. .NET 4.0 through 4.5.2 will all report `4.0.x` for the clr.dll version number.

You likely have the correct version installed already. If you really want to be sure, follow this MSDN article "[How to: Determine Which .NET Framework Versions Are Installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)"

Comment: all I know is that clr.dll version on the offline computer is 4.0.30319.1 versus a different computer (online) which version is 4.0.30319.11028. and they both had the same initial installation .net 4

Answer (score 0):

1. install .net 4.5.2 or whatever is latest from here: 
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642
   this will give you the latest .net 4 as well as .net 4.5.2 at this moment
2. if you want to code for .net 4 use visual studio to choose .net 4 as your project target